# 'No type class instance was found' on multi-parameter type class

Tags: typeclass, purescript

Is it reasonable to have multi parameter type classes in PureScript?

The compiler raises an unreasonable 'No type class instance was found' error (see [full output](https://gist.github.com/srid/6cdcee6a785979e3d53dd56ba439a273)) for the below type class definition:

```
class Transform model turn where
  transform :: turn -> model -> model
  delay :: Maybe turn -> Int
```

The error arises from the definition of the `delay` function which doesn't depend on the `model` type parameter. As evident from the compiler output linked above it substitutes a t0 for the absent model.

What is the proper way to fix this? Currently I workaround this issue by changing the kind of `turn` as below:

```
class Turnable model turn where
  runTurn :: turn model -> model -> model
  turnDelay :: Maybe (turn model) -> Int
```

Answer (score 1):

rightfold from the FP slack channel gave this answer:

> add fundep `| turn -> model`
>
> Then the instance is looked up only through `turn`

Consequently I changed the type class definition to this:

```
class Turnable model turn | turn -> model where
  runTurn :: turn -> model -> model
  turnDelay :: Maybe turn -> Int
```

This made the compiler happy. For details, consult [Functional dependencies](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functional_dependencies) (fundep) in the Haskell wiki and the [24 days of PureScript post](https://github.com/paf31/24-days-of-purescript-2016/blob/master/10.markdown).

Answer (score 0):

...in the old days we had used a Proxy (https://github.com/purescript/purescript-proxy) to help the compiler decide which instance to choose.
e.g. :

```
turnDelay :: Proxy model -> turn -> Int
turnDelay _ turn = .....
```

and call it by passing in a proxy:

```
turnDelay (Proxy :: Proxy FooModel) barTurn
```

I agree FunDeps are the right way to go.